# instalar visual estudio en el mismo equipo en discos duros diferentes con sistema diferente

Tags: visual-studio, windows10, windows7, visual-studio-2008

Tengo instalado visual studio 2008 en un disco duro con windows 7 , lo necesito ahi por que mis proyectos solo corren en esa version de windows aunque casi no lo ocupo solo cuando necesito hacer algo muy especifico, en otro disco duro en el mismo equipo tengo quiero instalar la misma version de visual studio pero no me lo permite me dice que me falta el visual studio framework , alguien ha logrado ejecutar visual de esta manera

solo necesito correr visual y conectarlo al team explorer para visualizar una solucion que estoy migrando a otro sistema pero todo desde windows 10.

Comment: Porque no solo abres la solucion del discoduro2 usando la version de Vs del discoduro1, copia la solucion del D2 al Disco 1

Comment: tengo una comptadora nueva y en windows 7 no existen drivers de nada para mi lap , entonces me es dificil trabajar sin doble monitor mas ahorita que estoy migrando y ocupo ver un codigo en una pantalla y programar en la otra , necesito abrir la solucion de vs 2008 en windows 10 pero no me permite windows 10 instalar ni visual ni el team fundation no se si sea problema del path o alguna cosa asi

Comment: y no me deja abrir la solucion del visual 2008 en el visual 2017 el cual si que tengo instalado y funcionando en ambos sistemas

Comment: Pues una vez migre un proyecto, pero primero cree una solucion en VS2017 despues en la carpeta creada de esta nueva solucion copie y pegue los proyectos de la solucion de VS2008, abri la solucion en VS2017y le de agregar proyectos existentes. Solo tuve problemas en una parte del codigo que no compilaba pero ajuste la clase, no se si quieras intentar algo similar, digo como prueba solo intenta con tu proyecto base.

Comment: tal vez me servira eso pq igual no pienso correrlo en windows 10 solo quiero tener abierta la solucion para poder verla en la segunda pantalla y programarlo o documentar unas cosas , pero teniendo la ventaje de buscar en la solucion , seguir las definiciones y ver las pantallas y las funciones que tiene cada boton en el diseñador